# openssl- failed to decrypt data generated by PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I am trying to use openssl on linux bash to decrypt the data generated by PHP code

I tried by passing -base64 -A, and mentioning -md sha256 after reading related questions on stackoverflow. But nothing worked.

```
$output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = "KEY";
    $secret_iv = "KEY";
    $string = "123456789ABCDEF"; 

   $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

    echo $output;

?>

NAMQy8pB7ZTjPacExtMBsg==
```

Then I tried to decrypt on linux:

```
echo "NAMQy8pB7ZTjPacExtMBsg==" |openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -K 905e17d5f5e4939d48bd04ff47f9de906375b87b67068b2ce5d1bbbbc8dca291 -iv 905e17d5f5e4939d -p
salt=0000000000000000
key=905E17D5F5E4939D48BD04FF47F9DE906375B87B67068B2CE5D1BBBBC8DCA291
iv =905E17D5F5E4939D0000000000000000
bad decrypt
140500719368080:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:592:


PHP Version :7.3.10

Openssl version on linux bash: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

I am expecting it to decrypt the data as I am passing the same key/iv. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP-function [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) has a 3rd parameter (`$raw_output`) that controls the format in which the result is returned. If the parameter is `FALSE`, the result is returned as a hexadecimal string (in lower case). This is the default. If the parameter is `TRUE`, the result is returned as binary string.

With regard to the use of the parameters `$key` and `$iv` in the `openssl_encrypt`-call, I suspect that the result should be returned as binary string. Therefore the current PHP-code must be modified and the value `TRUE` must be passed as 3rd parameter in the `hash`-function for both key and IV.

To display key and IV as hexadecimal strings (with regard to the OpenSSL-statement), use the PHP-function [`bin2hex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).

This results in:

```
Key (hex):       d7964f06c187b9ba129b0b9fd3db673fc8f83348e8fde4db339034c1944b89de
IV (hex):        d7964f06c187b9ba129b0b9fd3db673f
Output (Base64): vf6mWjgdOsBS2qE9U3/VCA==
```

If you use this result in the OpenSSL-statement:

```
echo vf6mWjgdOsBS2qE9U3/VCA== | openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -K d7964f06c187b9ba129b0b9fd3db673fc8f83348e8fde4db339034c1944b89de -iv d7964f06c187b9ba129b0b9fd3db673f
```

the decryption is successful.

**Update:**

If the PHP-code can't be modified, key and IV used in the OpenSSL-statement must be modified: In the posted code, the 32-bytes-key is expressed as a hexadecimal string, i.e. with 64 characters or 64 bytes. Of these, `openssl_encrypt` only considers the first 32 bytes, i.e. the *actual* key is:

```
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key), 0, 32);
```

The IV is still:

```
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
```

To display key and IV as hexadecimal strings (with regard to the OpenSSL-statement) `bin2hex` must be used as before and it results:

```
Key (hex):       6437393634663036633138376239626131323962306239666433646236373366
IV (hex):        64373936346630366331383762396261
Output (Base64): NAMQy8pB7ZTjPacExtMBsg==
```

The OpenSSL-statement:

```
echo NAMQy8pB7ZTjPacExtMBsg== | openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -K 6437393634663036633138376239626131323962306239666433646236373366 -iv 64373936346630366331383762396261
```

decrypts the ciphertext successfully.

Comment: Thank you! The decryption is successful now. But my problem is the PHP code is in another module where  I can't make change. 
Is there any way that I can decrypt  the data using openssl-statement, without changing PHP module?